# MySQL query, SELECT FROM with alias issue

Tags: mysql, alias

This query returns error code 1054 Unknown column 'Nb_P' in 'field list'.

```
SELECT Lot.LotNbPieces AS Nb_P, 
       LotValeurFonciere AS VF, 
       LotSurfCarrez AS M2  
FROM data_immo.Lot 
WHERE (Lot.LotType='Appartement' AND Lot.LotNbPieces=2 OR Lot.LotNbPieces=3) 
GROUP BY Nb_P, VF, M2;
```

Nb_P (stand for number of rooms/apartment) is known as 'Lot.LotNbPieces'. So do not understand this error. Could you give me some input on that ?

Moreover, I need to use those aliases to calculate average values. So, this above query would be modified this way,

```
SELECT Lot.LotNbPieces AS Nb_P, 
       LotValeurFonciere AS VF, 
       LotSurfCarrez AS M2, 
       avg(CASE WHEN Nb_P=2 THEN VF END) AS Moy_VF_2P, 
       avg(CASE WHEN Nb_P=3 THEN VF END) AS Moy_VF_3P, 
       avg(CASE WHEN Nb_P=2 THEN M2 END) AS Moy_M2_2P, 
       avg(CASE WHEN Nb_P=3 THEN M2 END) AS Moy_M2_3P  
FROM data_immo.Lot 
WHERE (Lot.LotType='Appartement' 
AND Lot.LotNbPieces=2 OR Lot.LotNbPieces=3) 
GROUP BY Nb_P, VF, M²;
```

Can we add in SELECT clause these calculation statements ? Is that a correct syntax ?

Many thanks for your feedback,

Answer (score 0):

In first query You are not using aggregation function  ..  so you should not use group by  ..  use DISTINCT in these cases

You are also using condition in wrong way

```
SELECT distinct Lot.LotNbPieces AS Nb_P, LotValeurFonciere AS VF, LotSurfCarrez AS M2  
FROM data_immo.Lot 
WHERE Lot.LotType='Appartement' AND (Lot.LotNbPieces=2 OR Lot.LotNbPieces=3)
```

for the second query
you can't use column name alias in select clause because the reference to the alias is obtianed by the db engine after the select clause is resolved  so you must repeat the code in you case when statement

```
SELECT Lot.LotNbPieces AS Nb_P
    , LotValeurFonciere AS VF
    , LotSurfCarrez AS M2
    , avg(CASE WHEN Lot.LotNbPieces=2 THEN LotValeurFonciere END) AS Moy_VF_2P
    , avg(CASE WHEN Lot.LotNbPieces=3 THEN LotValeurFonciere END) AS Moy_VF_3P
    , avg(CASE WHEN Lot.LotNbPieces=2 THEN LotSurfCarrez END) AS Moy_M2_2P
    , avg(CASE WHEN Lot.LotNbPieces=3 THEN LotSurfCarrez END) AS Moy_M2_3P  
FROM data_immo.Lot WHERE Lot.LotType='Appartement' 
AND (Lot.LotNbPieces=2 OR Lot.LotNbPieces=3) 
GROUP BY b_P, VF, M2
```

If the alias don't work in group by then you can solve just repeating the code

```
GROUP BY Lot.LotNbPieces 
    , LotValeurFonciere 
    , LotSurfCarrez
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, made the changes. Query looks the following: "SELECT DISTINCT Lot.LotNbPieces AS Nb_P, LotValeurFonciere AS VF, LotSurfCarrez AS M2, avg(CASE WHEN Nb_P=2 THEN VF END) AS Moy_VF_2P, avg(CASE WHEN Nb_P=3 THEN VF END) AS Moy_VF_3P, avg(CASE WHEN Nb_P=2 THEN M2 END) AS Moy_M2_2P, avg(CASE WHEN Nb_P=3 THEN M2 END) AS Moy_M2_3P FROM data_immo.Lot WHERE (Lot.LotType='Appartement' AND (Lot.LotNbPieces=2 OR Lot.LotNbPieces=3));" returns Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'Nb_P' in 'field list'. Any idea ? Thank you for your time

Comment: Ok I understand, query works based on your last input, Thank you